# Ubuntu Partitioning (Gparted Failed)

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, ubuntu-10.04

As title, I had try using Gparted and Gparted Live on CD/DVD, but both of them failed. Any other recommendation that I could try ?? (PS: I wanna resize the root drive as it is the only the drive it have > <)..

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly failed?

Comment: Gparted right click and resize was disabled whereas Gparted Live failed to boot in error message prompt(forgot the message)

Comment: try knoppix live cd: http://www.knoppix.org/

Comment: You can't resize a mounted (in use) DOS partition with gparted. You could also try systemrescuecd or pmagic live cds.

Comment: Definitely try using PartedMagic disk. You can't partition a mounted drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a live CD with ubuntu on it, and use fdisk command will do it.
If you want to resize the partition, you need to delete the current partition, and recreate it but larger : your data won't be lost. (normally, but i'd advice to back up your files.)
You can learn how to use fdisk here : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html